# Can not receive chat messages in Android using XMPP and aSmack

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, asmack

I am writing a chat client in Android using the XMPP protocol. I have used the asmack.jar as provided by 
http://asmack.freakempire.de/. The implementation works in plain Java (using smack.jar) which I have tested. But in Android, I can only send messages to the other client (he uses pidgin) and cannot receive messages from him. The app successfully connects to the server, logs in and appears online but simply doesn't receive any message.

My `processMessage()` never gets called nor does `chatCreated()` when a message is send to my client.

My Activity class:

```
package com.example.basicchat;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.AndroidConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackAndroid;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SmackAndroid.init(this);
        MainActivity2 xmppClient= new MainActivity2("jabber.org", 5222);
        try {
            xmppClient.login();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public class MainActivity2 implements MessageListener, ChatManagerListener, ConnectionListener {


        private String    server;
        private int        port;
        public MainActivity2( String server, int port )
    {
        super();

        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
    }
        private XMPPConnection    connection    = null;

        public void login() throws XMPPException
        {
            String username = "my_user";
            String password = "xxxxxxxx";
            login(username, password);

        }

        private void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException
        {
           AndroidConnectionConfiguration config = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(server,
                    port);
            connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
            connection.connect();
            connection.addConnectionListener(this);
            connection.login(userName, password);
            ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
            chatManager.addChatListener(this);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"listener set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // sendMessage("helloooo","command_server@jabber.org"); /* this mssg is sent */
        }

        private void sendMessage(String message, String to) throws XMPPException
        {
            Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(to, this);
            chat.sendMessage(message);
        }

        public void disconnect()
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        /** never gets called **/
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message)
        {
            /*********** Handle Request and construct response ******************/
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"mssg: "+message.getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (message.getType())
            {
            case chat:
                String jsonData = (null==message.getBody())?"":message.getBody();

                System.out.println(jsonData);
                break;
            case error:
                break;
            case groupchat:
                break;
            case headline:
                break;
            case normal:

                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(Chat arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Chat Created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (!arg1)
                arg0.addMessageListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

    }
```

}

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.basicchat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.basicchat.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please also paste your XMPP logs.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem ... does any body help me please ????

Answer (score 0):

You must implements `MessageListener` class for `MainActivity`  to receive chat messages